# Process.StartInfo.FileName coming up blank

Tags: c#

So, I am creating a C# program to run a command prompt command when a button is pressed, this is the code that executes when the button is pressed:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
    string arg = textBox1.Text + "& exit";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    string outp = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    StreamWriter myStreamWriter = process.StandardInput;
    myStreamWriter.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
    textBox2.Text = outp;
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Maybe it's something obvious that I am missing, if it is, I am sorry(I am kind of a beginner at C#), but I can't, for the life of me, figure out why I get an exception thrown out of system.dll that reads as follows:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in  System.dll
>     Additional information: Cannot start process because a file name has not been  provided.

However, I *have* provided a file name (line 5 of code snippet). Any help is GREATLY appreciated, thanks.
 P.S.
This code uses:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

To run properly.

Comment: I am sorry for previously commenting a comment asking for people to vote for this question, I just want to have a higher rep to be able to post comments and vote publicly for other people's questions too. I also thought that this was an OK question to ask and did not realize I would lose rep for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
process.StartInfo = startInfo; //Here problem is there, you are 
      //refreshing "process.StartInfo" with "startInfo". As "startInfo" is empty in your code.
//So use below code

 System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
 string arg = textBox1.Text + "& exit";
 startInfo.Arguments = arg;
 startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
 startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
 process.StartInfo = startInfo;
 process.Start();
```

Comment: Did you need to add escape characters to the filename shown above? 
Ie "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"
Or perhaps
@"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" ?

Comment: I did @"C"\..." and the path of cmd.exe is normal and unchanged

Comment: It works if you add "System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();" to the top